# How to mix html templates and $templateCache ones in the same app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've added the ui.bootstrap for angular to my project recently.
it comes with templates being added to the $templateCache programatically.

The rest of my app uses templates as html files from a views folder
i.e. views/directives/clip.html

I have an element directive called clip, I've made changes to its template. but when I upload my app to a staging server, I just get old versions of that template rather than the new one.

I've tried using something like this:

```
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.removeAll();
});
```

When I do this, the templates for the ui.bootstrap directives are removed and create an error

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined') {
            $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
        }
    });
});
```

When I do that, only template files of pages (routes) are uncached, but element directives are still cached.

What is a way in which I can remove all cached html templates and still keep the ui.bootstrap ones (Or any templates that are added programatically)

Thanks !

Comment: Your html pages are cached by browser, not by angular, so do not remove anything from $templateCache

Comment: I thought so too, but they don't get updated with the new ones.
The only thing that works is removing them from the templateCache.
And thus, forcing them to refresh.

Comment: One of the possible ways is to add http interceptor to add '?version=3' to all html requests (that do not exist in $templateCache).

Comment: The template cache is empty when the application starts. And the application starts every time you refresh the page. So if you refreshed and got an old version of the view, the browser, a proxy or the server is returning a cached version. But not angular. So emptying the cache at startup is useless. What are you trying to achieve? Loading a new version of a directive view without reloading the directive JavaScript code is something you should avoid. So what?

Comment: Can't you clear the browser cache? or that doesn't work? Is there some cache on your server which sends back old files? In Chrome dev console you can disable the browser cache.